# How do I create ridge capping along the ridge of a metal roof

Tags: edit-mode

I have created a simple building with fairly steep (pitched) roof and want to add ridge capping.

I tried using a method (see below) which was recommended to me in a previous question (how to add 'framing timber' to the edges of an octagon) but cannot get it to work on the roof maybe because the angle between the sides of the roof is a lot less than the angles on the side of an octagon ie 60 degrees I am not sure.
What I did was (edit mode) select the 'edge' which forms the ridge of the roof.
Apply Bevel setting the shape to 1 and the segments to 2
I then pressed AltE to Extrude Faces Along Normals as instructed in the other question but nothing seemed to happen this time and for the previous project also so I selected extruded along normals with the extrude 'tool'.
I enabling the offset even option.
Could not get it to work.

What am I doing wrong or what is the preferred method to create ridge capping on a roof?

The original question referred to can be viewed at  [How can I add framing timber to my octagonal tower](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292005/how-can-i-add-framing-timber-to-my-octagonal-tower)

Here is a simple blender model (original is too large in file size to upload). [image]

[image]

Comment: i would recommend linking the old question and adding a sketch/image to make it clear and easy to understand

Comment: I have updated my question to include link to original question and a simple blender object file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe <kbd>I</kbd> Inset with <kbd>I</kbd> individual would work better for you here:

[image]

.. followed By <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> Select Inverse, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Extrude Along Normals

Here's a route to a single ridge, starting from your topology:

[image]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> .. a loop in each side, dropped in place.
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>  from an end-on view, sliding to desired width
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> extrude new faces along normals, adjusted in the <kbd>F9</kbd> panel for a measured even thickness.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I cannot get that to work and besides I ONLY want to create the extra faces (to simulate ridge capping) on the single top edge of a 4 sided hipped roof as in my uploaded blender file with this question (forget about the octagon shaped object in the other question I asked)

Comment: @JohnArnold 4 sided? So you want it on the front and back faces of the house, too? Because I would have seen only the two sloped faces as "roof", while the vertical faces are walls of the house... or maybe you could add a sketch of what you actually want as Chris suggested in his comment above. And maybe a screenshot of your complex model - because I'm not sure if a solution provided for the "simpler" model you uploaded would work on the real model if I cannot see in which way it is simpler.

Comment: Very sorry its a 2 (NOT 4) sided hipped roof as per the blender object I uploaded. The more complex model only has a combination of 2 sided hipped roofs which intersect with each other but basically is a number of 2 sided hipped roofs. Please refer to my uploaded blender file.

Comment: @JohnArnold See edit.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Also I didn't realise that multiple edge cuts could be moved together.