# How to apply bevel evenly to an edge

Tags: edit-mode

I am attempting to add 'ridge capping' to a cone shaped octagon roof along each of the 8 edges using a method suggested to me in another post ([How can I add framing timber to my octagonal tower](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292005/how-can-i-add-framing-timber-to-my-octagonal-tower)). When I added the bevel the width of the bevel became narrower the closer to the top (point) of the roof.
I realise that this (hopefully) is controlled by a 'parameter' (width type?) but not sure and in attempting to correct what I 'set in concrete' during the add bevel it won't change. I have tried all the parameters for the bevel and could not get any to result in even sides.

Also after trying lots of things and running out of 'changes history' (eg use of ctrl Z to remove all changes) I tried to remove the edges created by the bevel selecting them and using 'dissolve edges' which removed them but it seems Blender somehow 'remembers'? where those edges are as when I tried to use bevel again I could not make the width wider than what I had previously done eg entering width as much as 2m the width would not go any wider - see image below where I have entered width of 2 meters and it is still narrow. I am only concerned with the upper (conical) roof.
So two questions very related.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since no-one else has answered this, I don't think you're going to be able to apply a constant width bevel when one end of the edge ends in a single vertex which connects to several faces.   As far as your other question is concerned, you've dissolved the edges of the bevel but the two vertices at the bottom end are still there, as is a single one underneath as you will see if you go into Vertex view. Those two are causing the problem when you try to bevel again. You can dissolve those in Vertex mode as you did with the edges.

Comment: Thanks John for taking the time to answer. I noticed that the (vertical) edges end at a very small octagonal face (I didn't merge at center) which appears (to me) to prevent the width of the bevel going wider at the top. I selected that face and scaled it slightly larger and then I was able to apply bevel of the width I wanted and which were constant. I should have noticed that before. Thanks again.