# How to add an edge to one side of a cube only

Tags: edit-mode

I am attempting to model a refueling shed (see image below with timber framing I want to add using an edge) and want to add an edge across 2 sides of the 'cube' only (the side in the image arrlowed and the opposite side) which I will expand later to form the timber 'framing' seen on the image between the windows and the bottom half of the wall. I tried doing it with loop cut and then selecting and deleting the edges drawn on the other two sides (but that of course removed a lot more. I tried using knife cut but had too much difficulty.
What is the answer please.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to inset the face and make the squares by subdividing the singular edges

Select an edge pair and use the *Subdivide* option in the object context menu <kbd>W</kbd> with machine tools <kbd>Q</kbd> with factory keybinds.

If the model needs to be beveled insetting (<kbd>I</kbd> key) the faces around the 4 squares is best as with tris like this the bevel modifier/operator needs supporting edges to keep it even, otherwise the bevel will be distorted (*Clamp Overlap* recommended).

Note that using *Sharp* as *Miter Outer* can cause shading issues with the internal squares, either using arc or harden normal will fix it, increasing segments number also fixes it but it will severely impact the poly count

[image]

Comment: Thanks Duarte.   I will try that. And yes I intended to use the bevel 'tool' to 'expand' the edges etc as I learned when I posted this question (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292005/how-can-i-add-framing-timber-to-my-octagonal-tower) some time ago.   Thanks again for another method and something else I have now learned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do an edge loop cut on the face with parallel sides (which aligns the edges with the bottom edges) and then select the edges not required and right click and dissolve edges? That seems to work but is it the preferable method?